# I received a .ejs file through the res.render method but the webpage remains the same

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

I am trying to implement user authentication using passport-local-mongoose and created a login page, after authenticating successfully I used the res.render() method to send the dashboard page but the webpage doesn't update despite the browser receiving it.

[ajax request handling on click event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAVx5.png)

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
userCred = {}
username = document.getElementById('username').value
password = document.getElementById('password').value
userCred.username = username
userCred.password = password

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('POST', `http://localhost:3000/users/login/${username}`)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(userCred))


xhr.onload = function () {
    if (!(xhr.status === 200)) {
        alert('error')
        return
    }

}})
```

[app.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXFc8.png)

```
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.json());  

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.all('*', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('recieved request for ' +  req.url + ' using ' + req.method)
    next()
})


app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.ejs', {layout:false})
})
    
app.use('/users', userRouter)

app.listen(3000)
```

[userRouter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV9pU.png)

```
userRouter = express.Router()
users = require('../models/users.js')


userRouter.post('/login/:username', passport.authenticate('local' , { failureRedirect: '/'}), (req, res,next) => {
    username = req.params.username
    res.redirect('/users/' + username)
    next()

})

userRouter.get('/:username', (req, res,next) => {
    res.render('../public/user.ejs', {layout:false})
    next()

})

userRouter.post('/signup/:username', (req, res, next) => {
    user.register(new user({ username: req.body.username }), req.body.password, (err, user) => {

        res.end()
    })
})


module.exports = userRouter
```

[res received by browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn2wh.png)

https://github.com/Johan511/stackex1.git
(link to all the files)

Comment: Can you please replace the links with the actual code. It's actualy much easier to copy&paste the code then making and uploading screenshots.

Comment: my bad, I am really new to programming and wasn't aware of the proper etiquette

Comment: In the `userRouter.post('/login/:username....` you should not redirect. Instead respond with http status 200 if login OK or 401/403 if something wrong. Then in the xhr response check the status code and if it is 200 then redirect on client side using for example `location.href = '/users/' + username;`. XHR request does not do anything with the response even if it is html, it is not supposed to.